# Non analytic ideals on $\omega$

Tags: set-theory, ideals

I would like to gather examples of NON analytic ideals on $\omega$.

However, I have found nothing in the books and papers I have consulted.

Could anyone tell me some reference/s?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot certain the meaning of 'analytic ideals'. What is the meaning of that? My thought is: since every subset of $\omega$ would be considered as a point in the Cantor set, we can construct the corresponding subset of the Cantor set with given ideal therefore we can talk about analyticity of ideal. Am I correct?

Comment: @tetori Yes, that's the meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every non principal prime ideal over $\omega$ is both Lebesgue non measurable and does not have Baire property so it cannot be analytic.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I was wondering if there are "explicit" examples of ideals, in the same way that one describes the "summable ideal" or the ideal of "sets with density 0"... (I would like to avoid dealing with the Axiom of Choice, Continuum hypothesis, Martin axiom and this sort of stuff...)

Comment: There is a perfect set of independent family of subsets of $\omega$. Any non analytic subset of this will generate a non analytic ideal. The set of all well ordering of integers is Pi-1-1 complete. Is this explicit enough?

Comment: @GregSmiley It is consistent with ZF that every subset of reals is Borel, so I think that there is no example given from ZF only.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful (and explicit enough) answers!

Answer (score 1):

We just submitted a paper, http://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.05699v1.pdf, in Section 2 you can find examples of quite natural coanalytic ideals (and more).

Comment: What is the relationship between coanalytic ideals and non-analytic ideals?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese A coanalytic ideal is analytic iff it is Borel.